# UnsatisfiableError: pyqt and py-opencv in conflict

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, anaconda, pyqt4

For my College project, i tried installing pyqt with command `conda install pyqt=4` but it shows error as shown below (even this error comes after solving environment for few minutes).
I am new to these stuffs, can anyone please help me over this!

```
(tensorflow_cpu) F:\BE project\TensorFlow\addons\labelImg>conda install pyqt=4

Solving environment: failed
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict: 
- py-opencv
- pyqt=4 

Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Comment: Did you read and act upon the advice given in the last line of the message?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that py-opencv requires python 3.6 or above where as pyqt=4 requires python2.7. Hence there will be a conflict between these two packages.

To avoid this conflict and use both the packages together, follow the below steps. Note that here the pyqt version will get upgrade to 5.9.2

Commands:

Create a new conda environment to avoid package mismatches.

```
conda create -n pyqt python=3.6
```

Here pyqt is the conda environment name

Activate the environment:

```
activate pyqt
```

Install py-opencv

```
conda install -c anaconda py-opencv
```

Install pyqt package:

```
conda install -c alges pyqt
```

While executing this step, pyqt version will be 5.9.2

Now you will be able to use both the packages with python3.6